# Using a secondary APN just for a specific Android Application

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile, connectivity, apn

Is it possibile to use a secondary APN just for a specific Android Application and let the current APN to be used by the other applications (in the same time)?

If it is, how?

I would like to know a code about how to set that secondary APN without to change the current one, thank you.

Answer (score -2):

It's possible via 3rd-party VPN but i don't think that there's custom APN VPN Changer. However, there's several VPN Client that has this feature such as `clash`, it has connection `rules` wich traffic that you want to use for each apps. It's defined by package name `com.android.your_game_package` using a yaml or json config inside `clash`. It's support for XRay, V2ray, Trojan VPN Protocol. Read more about it here:

https://github.com/Dreamacro/clash
https://github.com/Kr328/ClashForAndroid